# New to Web Development: SPA or Server-side App?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am relatively new to web development (basic HTML, CSS) and am looking for guidance on where to focus my energy. After a few weeks research, I feel a little lost!

I am looking to start a small project that would ideally provide both desktop and mobile browser UIs (with the possibility of presenting the Mobile UI as a Hybrid App via PhoneGap or similar).

Should I concentrate on Single Page App development using a client-side javascript framework? This feels like the most 'forward ready' approach given the focus on SPAs and the buzz around many of the frameworks (which may provide me some much needed architectural guidance and direction).

Alternatively, is a more traditional server based model the best place to start (e.g. RoR)? Is it a matter of walking (server-based) before running (SPA)?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for something that will scale on mobile platforms, use a JavaScript framework for providing the look and feel, but don't perform too many operations on the client.  Client intensive operations (JavaScript) annihilate mobile phone batteries and your users will not thank you for it.  In fact, they will avoid using your app at all costs, finding ways to bypass it.  Opera provided a shortcut for this on mobiles, since pages are processed in the cloud and served up to mobiles by the Opera browser as a static page.  Most people don't use Opera on their mobile devices, so you can't rely on this.

Having implemented something like this many times in the past, I would design something that uses a JavaScript framework for presentation and nothing else.  Implement as much as you can in the cloud.

Comment: this question needs closing, not answering; sorry

Comment: I've seen worse.  At least it's a question and not "Can you do my homework for me" ;-)

Comment: umm... ."help me choose a technology" questions do not belong here. It's hard to answer those objectively

Comment: wouldn't offloading work to the server cause increased bandwidth usage? Batteries grow quite fast, but bandwidth still costs money.

Comment: Not if you are using JSON as a transport encoding.  You can render pages using a framework like I said, meaning you transfer small JSON blobs to update the page.  But all the heavyweight logic is performed using server CPU.  Since most things are supported by DB's, it makes more sense to process data on the server and send down exactly what you need to the client.  Results are cacheable meaning the overall cost for common queries is reduced.

Comment: what about stuff that _can_ be done client-side-only? For example, sorting a table can be done client-side

Comment: Thanks Craig and Jan for the comments. I did suspect that this type of question may have been too broad for SO, so I apologise for the vagueness.

Comment: @Jan - sorting should be done on the server.  If you have 10000 rows, you have to send all 10000 rows to the client (bandwidth) for a proper sort to take place.  However, if you sort on the server in the DB, you can send down the first ten rows (typically all the user is interested in before they narrow their search).  There are scroll to view implementations now that fetch more data from the server from the current view as the user scrolls the page.  That or pagination buttons are implemented.  "Google Search" is a really good example of how it should be done.

Comment: At the risk of continuing my faux pas, are you able to recommend a better forum for this type of question?

Comment: You could try the YUI (Yahoo) forums or IRC rooms.  People always willing to help and offer good advice on there.

Comment: As closing pointer, you can actually implement your client and server side code in JavaScript and have them coexist in the same module.  Look at nodeJS for implementing JavaScript on the server.

Comment: Thanks once again Craig.